# GeoCoordinateWatcher in windows phone doesnt fire the event at given intervals

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have the below code which fires the GeoCoordinateWatcher PositionChanged event for every 0.5 meteres .It might be less.But thats my requirement.

The issue is when i am walking with phone the code doesnt fire the event at every 0.5 meters instead it fires the event after 0.5 meters randomly.And sometimes when i move fast it fires few events one after another immediately.

Can anybody help me with how to ensure it fires the positionchanged event for every 0.5 meters accurately .

```
            watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
            if (watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Granted)
            {
                watcher.MovementThreshold = 0.5;//in meters
            }

            watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);    //   PositionChanged events occur whenever your position changes     
            watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_OnStatusChanged);
            watcher.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

GeoPositionAccuracy should definitely be set to high.  I believe Default will use cellular/wifi to determine location whereas High will use the GPS on the phone.  Default is mainly used when you are just looking for a general location.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but I don't know why you are using the following code:

> if (watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Granted) 
>   {
>       watcher.MovementThreshold = 0.5;//in meters 
>   }

Why do you need to check the permission for watcher? Why not go ahead and immediately define the MovementThreshold? This might help improve the speed of your data. Also, you set GeoPositionAccuracy to Default. If you want it to fire more accurately, use **GeoPositionAccuracy.High**

Answer (score 0):

Also, I am pretty sure there you can also do the following to get the details for horizontal and vertical accuracy data:

```
 e.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy.ToString();
 e.Position.Location.VerticalAccuracy.ToString();
```